# How to write two model rewrites

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, model

Is this a valid rewrite? I can't seem to find the answer to: How to rewrite to models from the same Module?

Do I need to separate the classes or can I put both under rewrites? This is not working so far.

These are the two models I want to rewrite.

- Module_Reminder_Model_Reminder
- Module_Reminder_Model_Observer

  ```
      <config>
          <modules>
              <Module_Reminder>
                  <version>1.0</version>
              </Module_Reminder>
          </modules>
          <global>
              <models>
                  <adjreminder>
                      <rewrite>
                          <reminder>Module_Reminder_Model_Reminder</reminder>
                          <observer>Module_Reminder_Model_Observer</observer>
                      </rewrite>
                  </adjreminder>
              </models>
          </global>
      </config>
  ```

Comment: Its look like wrong can you please share complere class name that you  want to rewrite and `adjreminder`'s config.xml

Comment: you need to add both separately

Comment: From which element? `<adjreminder>`

Comment: I have resolved the issue. I'll soon post the solution. Or I can delete the question. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to rewrite the two models `Reminder.php` and `Observer.php` of a module which has `adjreminder` as a model alias, then this is valid.

You should look in the `\Mage_Core_Model_Config::getGroupedClassName` method to understand why. The line `if (isset($config->rewrite->$class)) {` says that you only have to write one node `rewrite` (Magento will then check all the childs nodes).